# How to show some columns of 3 tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables: `Prestam, Book, User`.

Table **Prestam**

1. Id_Prestam
2. Date_Prest
3. Date_Dev
4. Id_Book   'link
5. Id_User   'link

Table **Book**

1. Id_Book
2. Title

Table **User**

1. Id_User
2. Name
3. Last Name

Here is my SQL code, although there is an error in the syntax, specifically in:

```
, Pr.Id_User = User.Id_User
```

---

```
SELECT 
    Pr.Id_Prestam, Pr.Date_Prest, Pr.Date_Dev,
    Lbr.Title,
    Usr.Name, Usr.Last Name 
FROM 
    Prestam Pr, Book Lbr, User Usr 
WHERE 
    Pr.Id_Book = Lbr.Id_Book, Pr.Id_User = Usr.Id_User
```

The goal is to show me the following:

- Id_Prestam
- Date_Prest
- Date_Dev
- Title
- Name
- Last Name

Is there any way to make this possible?

I had heard about creating views but, I do not know how to handle it

```
CREATE VIEW List AS
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve that particular syntax error, since you have given the `User` table the alias of `Usr` you need to change this:

`, Pr.Id_User = User.Id_User`

To this:

`, Pr.Id_User = Usr.Id_User`

Then you'll need to take a look at using the `JOIN` statement to join tables together. The `WHERE` statement doesn't allow you to join tables together.

Comment: ok, corrected, I am using SQLite Database Browser and I get syntax error

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your SQL code.
In this part of the query, you are referring to the `User` table alias :

```
, Pr.Id_User = User.Id_User
```

But that alias does not exist, it is called `Usr` instead.

Bottom line, you should be using `JOIN`s instead of stuffing your relationships in the `WHERE` clause.

Here is a new query :

```
SELECT 
    Pr.Id_Prestam,
    Pr.Date_Prest,
    Pr.Date_Dev,
    Lbr.Title,
    Usr.Name,
    Usr.Last Name 
FROM Prestam Pr
INNER JOIN Book Lbr on Pr.Id_Book = Lbr.Id_Book
INNER JOIn User Usr on Pr.Id_User = Usr.Id_User
```

Comment: I am using SQLite Database Browser and I get syntax error

Comment: which erreur are you getting ?

Comment: the operator is missing in the query `JOIn User Usr on Pr.Id_User = Usr.Id_User`

Comment: While they should be using this form, yes, you should at least explain what the original problem was.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse : point taken, I added an explanation of the original issue to my answer

Comment: ...Uh, the original query doesn't look like that (anymore - and didn't at the time of the edit), and wasn't the only problem anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can do some sort of join on the tables.

i.e.

```
select * 
from Prestam P 
inner join Book B on P.ID_Book = B.ID_Book
inner join User U on P.ID_User = U.ID_User
```

Comment: but, `FROM Prestam Pr,Book Lbr,User Usr`,I do not include in the code?

Comment: No, not in a join like the one I showed.  It might also depend on what RDBMS you're using.  I use MS sql-server

Comment: I am using SQLite Database Browser and I get syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Join Prestam with the other 2 tables:

```
SELECT 
Prestam.Id_Prestam, Prestam.Date_Prest, Prestam.Date_Dev, 
Book.Title, 
User.Name, User.`Last Name`
FROM 
    (Prestam INNER JOIN Book ON Prestam.Id_Book = Book.Id_Book) 
        INNER JOIN User 
        ON Prestam.Id_User = User.Id_User;
```

Comment: I am using SQLite Database Browser and I get syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Solution --> change coma to AND

```
SELECT 
    Pr.Id_Prestam, Pr.Date_Prest, Pr.Date_Dev,
    Lbr.Title,
    Usr.Name, Usr.Last Name 
FROM 
    Prestam Pr, Book Lbr, User Usr 
WHERE 
    Pr.Id_Book = Lbr.Id_Book AND Pr.Id_User = Usr.Id_User
```